# How can I read values from an xml file in a fxml file?

Tags: java, xml, javafx, javafx-8, fxml

I am newbie to JavaFX, and as a similar way that is done in Android Studio, I would like to have a file called **strings.xml** where I can store some resources that can be read from an **fxml file**. For example, if I have the following code in **strings.xml**:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My App Name</string>
</resources>
```

I would like to do something like this in the fxml file:

```
text="@string/app_name"
```

How is it possible to achieve that?

Comment: One general idea: you could implement a [`ResourceBundle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) that read and parsed your XML file, and then pass an instance to the `FXMLLoader`. Then use the standard FXML [resource resolution](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#resource_resolution). Alternatively, if you are not tied to using XML, just use a standard [`PropertyResourceBundle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PropertyResourceBundle.html) and define a regular properties file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use internationalized strings within FXML files in a way similar to Android's resources. There are some differences:

1. The resource files are `.properties` files instead of `.xml`. The variables are defined in a different way too:

   ```
   variable.name_1=Hello
   variable.name_2=World
   ```

   (Note missing `<resource>` tags, it is just plain `[var_name]=[value]`).
2. To reference a string in a FXML file, you use a `%` instead of an `@string/`. For example:

   ```
   <Button
       fx:id="button1"
       text="%variable.name_1"
   />
   ```

That's it. I recommend searching for `ResourceBundle` as this explains how the property files should be named for the right language to be chosen. Also, that bundle can be used for adding internationalized variables to your code as well.